# Generate path string of subfolder in the working directory for R

Tags: r, file

In R, I want to load a file in a subfolder in working directory. But For convinent, I want to generate path of this folder to combine with file which i want to access. I don't know how to do it.

Please help me.

Thank a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Use `file.path`

```
> file.path(getwd(), "yourpath")
[1] "C:/Users/john/Documents/yourpath"
```

Comment: How do it if i don't want input my path instead of i use just the name of this folder. Example: my file i want to load is doing and fullpath is "/home/user/.../doing". But my working directory is "/home/user", and i want to load file in doing folder just with some thing short with doing name